# Виджет на пустые данные авторизации

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qmessagebox

У меня есть три окна, главное окно, окно с авторизацией и тест. 
В окне авторизации данные заполняются пользователем отправляются в БД. 
После нажатия кнопки  и в случае пустых полей необходимо чтобы появлялось окно  предупреждающее о том, что данные не заполнены и в БД ничего не отправлялось.

**main.py:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit, QGridLayout, QMessageBox)
from titul import Ui_mainWindow
from login import Ui_Login
from test import Ui_Test
from Leksia import Ui_Leksia
import pymysql
from config import host, user, password, db_name

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_mainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.connection = pymysql.connect(
            host=host,
            port=3306,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            database=db_name,
            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
        )
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

        self.Button_startTest.clicked.connect(self.openLogin)
        self.Button_runLR.clicked.connect(self.openLeksia)

    def openLeksia(self):
        self.leksia = LeksiaWindow()
        self.close()
        self.leksia.show()

    def openLogin(self):
        self.login = LoginWindow(self.connection)
        self.close()
        self.login.show()


class LeksiaWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Leksia):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LeksiaWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.returnToMain)

    def returnToMain(self):
        self.close()
        w.show()


class TestWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Test):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


class LoginWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Login):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        super(LoginWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connection = connection
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.check_password)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.opentest)

    def opentest(self):
        self.fio = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.grupp = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO students (ФИО, Номер_группы) VALUES ('{self.fio}', '{self.grupp}')")
        self.connection.commit()

        self.test = TestWindow()
        self.close()
        self.test.show()

    def check_password(self):
        msg = QMessageBox()

        if self.lineEdit_2.text() == 'Username' and self.lineEdit_3.text() == '000':
            msg.setText('Данные отправлены')
            msg.exec_()
            app.quit()
        else:
            msg.setText('Введите данные')
            msg.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**tityl.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_mainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, mainWindow):
        mainWindow.setObjectName("mainWindow")
        mainWindow.resize(1100, 800)
        mainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        mainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(mainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Button_runLR = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button_runLR.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 310, 271, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.Button_runLR.setFont(font)
        self.Button_runLR.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(227, 210, 255);")
        self.Button_runLR.setObjectName("Button_runLR")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1101, 801))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images.jpg"))
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.Button_startTest = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button_startTest.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 530, 271, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Tahoma")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.Button_startTest.setFont(font)
        self.Button_startTest.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(227, 210, 255);")
        self.Button_startTest.setObjectName("Button_startTest")
        self.Button_Rezylt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button_Rezylt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 420, 271, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.Button_Rezylt.setFont(font)
        self.Button_Rezylt.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(227, 210, 255);")
        self.Button_Rezylt.setObjectName("Button_Rezylt")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 100, 381, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(227, 210, 255);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label.raise_()
        self.Button_runLR.raise_()
        self.Button_startTest.raise_()
        self.Button_Rezylt.raise_()
        self.label_2.raise_()
        mainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(mainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, mainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        mainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("mainWindow", "Главная"))
        self.Button_runLR.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Начать лабораторную \n"
"работу"))
        self.Button_startTest.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Начать тест"))
        self.Button_Rezylt.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Посмотреть результаты"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Изучение этапов преобразования биосигналов"))
```

**login.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets



class Ui_Login(object):
    def setupUi(self, Login):
        Login.setObjectName("Login")
        Login.resize(1100, 800)
        Login.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Login)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 120, 581, 41))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(198, 212, 255);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 440, 141, 71))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(198, 212, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 310, 141, 31))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(198, 212, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 190, 61, 41))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(198, 212, 255);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 260, 331, 31))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lineEdit_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lineEdit_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 360, 331, 31))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lineEdit_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lineEdit_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-4, -8, 1111, 811))
        self.label_4.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.label_4.setText("")
        self.label_4.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images2.jpg"))
        self.label_4.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_4.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.label_3.raise_()
        self.label_2.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_2.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_3.raise_()
        Login.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Login)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Login)




    def retranslateUi(self, Login):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Login.setWindowTitle(_translate("Login", "Авторизация"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Login", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Для прохождения теста необходимо заполнить ФИО и номер группы</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Login", "Продолжить"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Login", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Номер группы</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Login", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">ФИО</span></p></body></html>"))
```

**test.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Test(object):
    def setupUi(self, Test):
        Test.setObjectName("Test")
        Test.resize(1100, 800)
        Test.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Test)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        Test.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Test)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Test.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(Test)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1100, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        Test.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.retranslateUi(Test)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Test)

    def retranslateUi(self, Test):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Test.setWindowTitle(_translate("Test", "Тест"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не уверен что правильно понял, то что вы хотите сделать.

Но предложу попробовать заменить класс `LoginWindow`:

```
class LoginWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Login):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        super(LoginWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connection = connection
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.check_password)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.opentest)

    def opentest(self):
        self.fio = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.grupp = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO students (ФИО, Номер_группы) VALUES ('{self.fio}', '{self.grupp}')")
        self.connection.commit()

        self.test = TestWindow()
        self.close()
        self.test.show()

    def check_password(self):
        msg = QMessageBox()

        if self.lineEdit_2.text() == 'Username' and self.lineEdit_3.text() == '000':
            msg.setText('Данные отправлены')
            msg.exec_()
            app.quit()
        else:
            msg.setText('Введите данные')
            msg.exec_()
```

на

```
class LoginWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Login):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        super(LoginWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.connection = connection
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        
#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.check_password)
#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.opentest)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.check_password)              # +++

    def opentest(self):
#        self.fio = self.lineEdit_2.text()
#        self.grupp = self.lineEdit_3.text()

        self.cursor.execute(
            f"INSERT INTO students (ФИО, Номер_группы) VALUES ('{self.fio}', '{self.grupp}')"
        )
        self.connection.commit()

        self.test = TestWindow()
        self.test.show()
        self.close()

    def check_password(self):
        self.fio = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.grupp = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        if not self.fio or not self.grupp:    
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Введите данные для авторизации.'
            )
            return            
        elif self.fio != 'Username' or self.grupp != '000':    
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Не правильно ввели данные для авторизации.'
            )              
            return     

        self.opentest()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]